# Scan online EXT4 using LVM snapshot?

Tags: lvm, ext4, snapshot

Can you make a trustworthy EXT4 filesystem-scan of an online filesystem, e.g. root, by taking a LVM snapshot and then do a scan on the snapshot, something like:

1. Make a snapshot:
   `lvcreate --snapshot --size 1G --name lv_root_SS --chunksize 4k /dev/VG1/lv_root`
2. EXT4 scan:
   `e2fsck -f /dev/dm-3` (device-name of the new shapshot is dm-3)
3. Remove the snapshot:
   `lvremove --yes VG1/lv_root_SS`

Will that work?

`e2fsck` doesn't complain and seem to do the scan just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do this, and there’s even a tool for that: [`lvcheck`](https://github.com/BryanKadzban/lvcheck). This follows the same approach as your description, with some additions:

- it lists all active LVs (which can be checked using a snapshot)
- it checks how long it’s been since the last check for each LV
- for each LV, snapshot it, run `fsck`, delete the snapshot
- LVs which pass the check have their last check timestamp updated (in the real volume)
- LVs which fail can be listed in an email

You can set this up in a periodic job (using cron or a systemd timer for example), and it will make sure your file systems are checked and updated as appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

There is actually an `e2scrub` systemd service included with e2fsprogs.  This does the same thing as `lvscan` but is kept uptodate with e2fsprogs.